# Best way to encode data

Tags: php, database, compression, encode

I have huge amount of data in my database whith format  :

```
lat;lon;speed;sec:lat;lon;speed;sec......
```

for example:

```
 53.284534;50.227268;67;0:53.285481;50.226627;68;6:53.286429;50.226042;66;12:.......
```

format is lattitude, longitude, speed, number of second from beginning.
length of each string is from 1000 to 100000.
I try to compress it before putting in database via gzcompress() and base64_encode().
In case of length of initial string 7607 symbols after gzcompress and base64_encode it will be 3444,
so compression is 50%.
Is any more effective way to compress  strings like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is clearly a strong correlation from sample to sample.  I would subtract from each sample the previous sample, except of course for the first one.  I would encode each difference as an [integer of variable length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity) (not as text but in binary).  For lat and long I would multiply by 1,000,000 on the assumption (which you need to verify) that there are never more than six digits after the decimal.  The second and third samples would each require only six bytes.

*Then* would I compress with gzip.

Answer (score 1):

Try just storing them as binary floats. This is very simple and it's very fast.
Each number would use 4 bytes and that would make it possible to use them directly from within your code.

Or if you need them more precise, multiply each component by a pre-definied value (which may differ for each component), and store as 32-bit integer words.

Comment: If further space-saving is needed, you can of course try gzcompress() on the binary data. Multiplied integer values might compress different from floats (it's a bit difficult to predict which would compress better, but I tend to believe that the integers would compress well, as there would probably be a lot of duplicate byte streams). Bzip2 and lzma are also two very nice and quick compression methods worth mentioning (lzma is quickest).

Comment: Thinking about it; you could also store the first set of values as absolute values, then after this, store only the differences. This would compress very well. If you're using integers, you could store the first set as 32-bit integers, then the difference-sets as 16-bit  or even 8-bit words, depending on how large the changes are. If storing bytes, and the byte values are exceeded, you could store two difference sets for a single update. (Eh, do I make sense?)

Comment: -And the "difference sets" would probably compress very, very well.